# Configure a custom store in ASP.NET Identity 2.x

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, asp.net-identity, owin

I've already developed an implementation to the following ASP.NET Identity interfaces: `IUserLoginStore<TUser>`, `IUserClaimStore<TUser>`, `IUserRoleStore<TUser>`, `IUserPasswordStore<TUser>`, `IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser>`.

Furthermore, I'm using OWIN/Katana, so I need to configure this by code during startup.

How do I provide/configure my custom store implementation to ASP.NET Identity?

*Note: I've been searching a simple and clear tutorial on how to achieve this and I can't find one.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default code created in an MVC 5.2 application, the identity configuration is done in `App_Start\IdentityConfiguration.cs`.

To use your own store instead of the default one, change the first line in the `ApplicationUserManager.Create()` method. By default it is

```cs
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
  new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

By changing it, you can inject your own `IUserStore` implementation.

If you also want to change the `ApplicationUser` type to use your own (or to simply rename `ApplicationUser` to something more suitable, that is done by changing the generic argument to `ApplicationUserManager`

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you for the hint! Today I dropped another Q&A I decided to remove because it was someway off-topic here in SO. BTW, do you know if there's some standard test suite to check that an ASP.NET Identity custom provider works?

Comment: No, there's none that I'm aware of, but it would be useful to have one.

Comment: Yeah, because I've created a new Redis-backed custom storage implementation, and now I'm stuck because I can't provide reliable integration tests...